# How can I use a single invariant command to run an executable with CMake independent of what generator is being used?

Tags: cmake

I know that I can compile any target with `cmake --build . --target Foo` independent of what generator is being used, no matter it's make, ninja, Xcode, or Visual Studio, but I can't seem to figure out the command to execute it that's independent of what generator is being used. Is there something like `cmake --run --target Foo`? It would be nice not having to write

```
# pseudo code
if make or ninja
 ./Foo
elif Xcode
 ./Debug/Foo
elif Visual Studio
 ./Debug/Foo.exe
```

Comment: You could probably create a custom target to run the executable.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for doesn't make sense to me. Make and Ninja generators are single-config generators. The generated buildsystem is for a single build configuration/type. Visual Studio and Ninja Multi-Config are multi-config generators. Multi-config generators will generate multiple binaries, and naturally those multiple binaries cannot all be at the same path.

You could configure your multi-config buildsystems to output to path with the configuration name in the path using [the `-B` argument to the configure command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#generate-a-project-buildsystem).

Even if there was something like what you're asking for, it'd still need an argument to pick which configuration's binary you want to run for multi-config buildsystems (CMake usually uses "`--config`" for these commandline arguments. Ex. [for build](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-config), [for install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-install-config). CTest uses [`-C`/`--build-config`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html#cmdoption-ctest-C)).

Note that you can have some control over where binaries go in general with [`CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), [`CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html), [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) and other related variables and target properties. But note from the documentation (Ex. [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)) that:

> Multi-configuration generators ([Visual Studio](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#visual-studio-generators), [`Xcode`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Xcode.html#generator:Xcode), [`Ninja Multi-Config`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Ninja%20Multi-Config.html#generator:Ninja%20Multi-Config)) append a per-configuration subdirectory to the specified directory unless a generator expression is used.

What you could do (I suppose (if you wanted (and if it suits your needs))) is to write a script that just runs one of them taking a configuration argument from an environment variable instead of from a commandline, but that really wouldn't be so much of a difference from manually selecting a path of an executable to run.

Comment: I guess the answer is no. But I think it could make sense if there's something like `cmake --run --target Foo --config Debug`.

Comment: @user3667089 sure. but the fact is that there is no such thing at the time of this writing (CMake 3.26). You could write a feature request.